# Show data on single row instead of two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can you see in the image the result of the query? How can I leave the inputs and outputs in a single row, as well as the time and date?

```sql
SELECT
    TR.Part, TR.Descripcion,
    TIO.Date, 
    M1 = CASE WHEN TIO.TypeOperation = 1 THEN 'Salio Almacen' END, 
    M2 = CASE WHEN TIO.TypeOperation = 0 THEN 'Entro Almacen' END,
    TIO.TypeOperation 
FROM
    Mant.Tool_InOut TIO 
JOIN
    Mant.Tool_Register TR ON TIO.idTools = TR.Id 
WHERE
    CAST(TIO.Date AS date) BETWEEN CAST(@f1 AS date) AND CAST(@f2 AS date)
```

[image: Attach]

Comment: Only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. also, white space and line breaks are a most for writing *any* language, and that includes SQL

Comment: The `DateOperation` values are different between each of the paired rows. We need more information about how you want to handle that. Also, the `cast(TIO.Date as date)` expression hurts index use for this query. You should do it like this instead, which still allows full use of indexes: `TIO.Date >= CAST(@f1 AS date) AND TIO.Date < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@f2 AS date))`

Comment: @DaleK Honestly, at this point they should really disable image use completely for anyone with less than 250 rep.

Answer (score 1):

Start here:

```
SELECT
    TR.Part, TR.Descripcion,
    TIO.Date AS Salio_Almacen_Date,
    , (SELECT TOP 1 ead.Date
       FROM Mant.Tool_InOut ead
       WHERE ead.idTools = TIO.idTools 
          AND ead.TypeOperation = 0
          AND ead.Date >0 TIO.Date

    ) As Entro_Almacen_Date
FROM
    Mant.Tool_InOut TIO 
JOIN
    Mant.Tool_Register TR ON TIO.idTools = TR.Id 
WHERE TIO.TypeOperation = 1
    AND TIO.Date >= CAST(@f1 AS date) AND TIO.Date < DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@f2 AS date))
```

Note this *won't work* for rows 10 and 11 in the sample, which are out of order from the others, or row 12, which has no matching TypeOperation 1 record. Row 7 will keep the `NULL` in the second place, but this seems correct.

The purpose here is to illustrate the challenge. Before we can give a complete solution, you need to understand the data better around why there are two rows in the first place, so you can tell us how you want to handle these edge cases.

Finally, note the change to the date checks in the WHERE clause. Avoiding the `CAST()` on the date field allows you to make better use of any index index on the field, which can have a drastic impact on query performance.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you want to know at any certain date if a part returned to the warehouse (almacen) or not.
If this is the case, then i guess it would be something like this:

```
SELECT
        TR.Part
    ,   TR.Descripcion
    ,   M1  =   'Salio'
    ,   T1  =   MIN(TS.[Date])
    ,   M2  =   'Entro'
    ,   T2  =   CASE WHEN MAX(TE.[Date]) > MAX(TS.[Date]) THEN MAX(TE.[Date] ELSE NULL END
    ,   TIO.TypeOperation 
    
FROM    Mant.Tool_Register  TR  
JOIN    Mant.Tool_InOut     TS  ON  TS.idTools          =   TR.Id
                                AND TS.TypeOperation    =   1
JOIN    Mant.Tool_InOut     TE ON   TE.idTools          =   TR.Id
                                AND TE.TypeOperation    =   0

WHERE   CAST(TS.Date AS date) BETWEEN CAST(@F1 AS date) AND CAST(@F2 AS date)
    AND CAST(TE.Date AS date) BETWEEN CAST(@F1 AS date) AND CAST(@F2 AS date)
```

Comment: Please see the comments below

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me at all, following the logic.
I give you the raw table data, as you can see in the column, the value at zero tells me when the product has left my warehouse and the number one when it has returned.
How can I place it next to each other.[image]

Comment: Which answer did not work for you? This table is not the same as the first..